# regex for delimited key-value pairs in a string?

Tags: regex, key-value

I have a string of key-value pairs that are delimited by a character in this format:

```
key1=value2&key2=value2& ... &keyN=valueN
```

Right now I'm unsafely assuming every two matches to be a key-value using this regex:

```
[^=&]+
```

Is there a safer way to pull these values out?

Comment: Yes, use a query string parser.

Comment: Which language, and what limitations do you have on the contents of the keys/values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PHP, I would probably try something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|&)([^=&]+)=([^=&]+)(?:&|$)/', $string, $matches);
```

For each match, 1 should be the key and 2 should be the value.

I can't test this where I am right now, but see if it works.

Comment: I would use `parse_str($string, $matches);` instead (see my above comment).

Comment: I didn't even realize there was a function for it. That looks even better.

Comment: PHP has a function for almost *everything* :)

Comment: Thanks; I like the regex solution but I will additionally try the query string parser.

Comment: In defense of my answer, RegEx is more exciting. Not that exciting is always best... :)